# Edit (colorized) terminal output before printing?

Tags: terminal, command-line, pdf, printing, color

A very similar question has already been [asked on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/229022/504387) but none of the answers works satisfactorily for me.

I can actually get *almost* what I want by simply:

1. Running the Terminal for the whole session with the terminal width that I want to appear in the printed output, and
2. Using Command-P (⌘-P) to print the terminal scrollback history (including colors!) to PDFwriter.

However, I can't then **edit the terminal scrollback history before printing**.

If I save the Terminal Saved Output with ⌘-S, I can edit the text, but it is plaintext only—no colors.

I want to use this printing capability to create correctly colorized example output PDFs demonstrating the correct use of command line tools, so it is important that I be able to edit the scrollback history for clarity.  For instance, if I make a typo halfway through a long demonstration, I don't want the mistake to appear in the PDF to confuse students/readers, but I also don't want to restart the demonstration.

Really I would like to be able to add page breaks at specific points, and have page numbering.  But at the very least I must be able to edit the text before it is turned into a PDF.

How can I do this on Mac OS X?

(I'm running Lion, 10.7.4.)

Answer (score 1):

Before starting your session, run the command `bash | tee stdout.rtf`. This starts a new bash session, recording the output in a file `stdout.rtf`. Now, simply edit `stdout.rtf` and print.

Comment: This doesn't work.  (a) The command output isn't displayed to my terminal, only the prompts are displayed; (b) The commands I type aren't entered into the file; (c) The command output is not in color.

Comment: I fixed it, it should work now!

Comment: Better, but [still no colors](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3515392/5419599).  You can't do it just with redirection.

Comment: try copying (m4-a m4-c) your terminal and paste it into a text editor that supports color. mod4 is normally the apple key.